Re-using existing field storage
I have an "article" node type, which has a list field article_type with 5 options.
When exporting the configuration, there are two config files:

field.field.node.article.field_article_type.yml
field.storage.node.field_article_type.yml

Now I want to create a paragraph-based content element called filter_article_type that shall use the same storage options.
This is not possible in the UI, but I could manually edit the paragraph field configuration  file to load the node storage configuration.
Is this a bad idea?
What problems will I encounter?

Yes that's a bad idea, as a rule of thumb never manually edit the config files. Everything you're supposed to do should be done via the admin interfaces.
But why would you want to do this?
If it's so they share common options then you could perhaps create a Article Type taxonomy vocabulary and then reference that on the node and paragraph.
That would allow the node/paragraph to essentially use the same options between them

yes, indeed for sharing the available options across those fields.
